# How to improve UNION of distinct values from the same table with different filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, union

Background:
The client has the possibility to create his own stock of vehicles. This means that he can display only the vehicles that match his criteria.
He also has the possibility to create frontend filters for users. These filters can synchronize between them. For example, if a user chooses something from filter X, the filter Y shows only the values that match X filter

The performance issue is at populating the frontend filters with values.
What I tried is something like this

```
;with v as(  
select something from vehicles  
where [his stock filters])  
select 'XFilter',X_id from v where Y_id > [value] and Z_id > [value] 
union  
select 'YFilter',Y_id from v where X_id > [value] and Z_id > [value] 
union  
select 'ZFilter',Z_id from v where X_id > [value] and Y_id > [value] 
union 
...
```

Multiple unions are going to be added to the query and adding different filters to all of them are hard to index or so I believe.
How should I proceed in order to obtain a better performance? Should I retrieve the data in a different way?

---

EDIT:
The Vehicles table have columns like the following

```
ID ColorID FueltypeID Mileage ...
1    1        1         1000
2    1        2         500
3    2        2         2000
4    2        1         1500
5    3        1         9000
6    3        2         8000
```

Using the above query, I want to extract all the distinct values for filters which have a limited  set of values, like colors and fueltypes. 
The expected result would be

```
     reference value
1     Color      1
2     Color      2
3     Color      3
4     Fueltype   1
5     Fueltype   2
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`, but the purpose of your query is not clear. Post sample data and expected output.

Comment: A `UNION` with a lot of datasets, with a large dataset, is going to be a performance killer. `UNION ALL` will help, *if* you aren't expecting duplicates. Not really sure, however, what you're trying to achieve here. Sample data and expected results would likely help here.

Comment: could you add please some data and desired output so we could try to figure out better?

Comment: It looks to me that your problem is more likely to be with the filters that you use than with the UNION statement. Have you tried separately your querys ?, if they are still slow, then your problem are the filters and you could show them to get an idea of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to tell what you want, but it appears to be:

```
with v as (  
      select something
      from vehicles  
      where [users stock filters]) 
     )
select f.which, f.id
from v cross apply
     (values ('XFilter', v.x_id, (case when Y_id > [value] and Z_id > [value] then 1 else 0 end) ),
             ('YFilter', v.y_id, (case when X_id > [value] and Z_id > [value] then 1 else 0 end) ),
             ('ZFilter', v.z_id, (case when X_id > [value] and Y_id > [value] then 1 else 0 end) )
     ) f(which, id, outcome)
where f.outcome = 1;
```

Comment: This is something I wanted to achieve. Thank you :) Just one small remark for other viewers, the selection is done with `f.which, f.id` and not with `v` alias.  I also used `distinct` in order to remove the duplicates

Comment: @Remus . . . You are totally correct.  I usually call the `values` construct `v`, but that was already used in this case.